# Curves on hypersurfaces generated by diagonal sums

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

This is related to an earlier question of mine ([(Non-)Existence of curves of low degree on affine and projective varieties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153015/non-existence-of-curves-of-low-degree-on-affine-and-projective-varieties)). It seems that the question is too difficult for specific surfaces, although according to Browning's book "Quantitative Arithmetic of Projective Varieties" the Hilbert scheme characterizing $m$-dimensional linear subvarieties of a non-singular hypersurface $X \subset \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ is empty provided that $m > (n-1)/2$.

My question now concerns hypersurfaces of the form

$$\displaystyle a_1x_1^{d_1} + a_2 x_2^{d_2} + \cdots a_n x_n^{d_n} = 0$$

where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}, d_i \in \mathbb{N}$. Further, we assume that $d_i \geq 2$. As referenced in my original question above, the case when $d_i = d_j$ for $i = j$ seems adequately handled by (perhaps others as well) Salberger.

The question is do such hypersurfaces contain curves of low degree, where the notion of 'low' is allowed to depend on the degree of the hypersurface?

If there aren't any results sufficiently general to handle the question in the generality implied above, what about the case when $d = d_1 = \text{lcm}(d_2, \cdots, d_n)$, and define $w_i = d/d_i$, and $w_2 \cdots w_n$ is small relative to $d$?

Comment: There is a huge difference between surfaces, i.e., hypersurfaces of dimension $2$, and higher-dimensional hypersurfaces.  Once $n$ is at least $6$, i.e., for every Fermat hypersurface $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^5$, there *will* be quadric surfaces $S$ contained in $X$.  So there will be many low degree curves in $X$: namely, the low degree curves contained in $S$.